# Comparing contents of 2 lists with values not ordered the same

Tags: clips, expert-system

I have these templates,

```
(deftemplate classroom
    (slot classroom_number (type INTEGER))
    (multislot students (type SYMBOL))
)

(deftemplate students_to_classroom_lookup
    (multislot students (type SYMBOL))
)
```

and these facts which represent classrooms and students belonging to that classroom.

```
(deffacts classrooms
    (classroom (classroom_number 1) (students Paul Lucy Peter Sebastian))
    (classroom (classroom_number 2) (students Peter Paul Lucy Sebastian Arthur))
    (classroom (classroom_number 3) (students Paul Lucy Peter))
    (classroom (classroom_number 4) (students Lucy Peter Paul))
)
```

Then I have this fact, that follows the "students_to_classroom_lookup" template and is entered by keyboard while the program is running.

`(students_to_classroom_lookup (students Paul Peter Sebastian Lucy))`

I want to find the classroom number that has exactly these and only these students.

Please note that content of,

`(students_to_classroom_lookup (students Paul Peter Sebastian Lucy))`

is based on user input, in another run of the program the contents of "students" could be Paul Sebastian Lucy Peter or just Lucy Peter Paul.

I have tried this rule:

```
(defrule match_classroom_and_students
    (classroom (classroom_number ?number) (students $?students))
    (students_to_classroom_lookup (students $?students_lookup&:(subsetp $?students $?students_lookup)))
=>
    (printout t "Classroom number " ?number crlf)
)
```

Output:

```
Classroom number 1
Classroom number 3
Classroom number 4
```

Expected output:

`Classroom number 1`

I appreciate all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an exact match of sets A and B, A must be a subset of B and B must be a subset of A:

```
(defrule match_classroom_and_students
    (classroom (classroom_number ?number) (students $?students))
    (students_to_classroom_lookup (students $?students_lookup&:(subsetp $?students $?students_lookup)
                                                             &:(subsetp $?students_lookup $?students)))
=>
    (printout t "Classroom number " ?number crlf)
)
```